# Built-in 'with' type method that returns the object it was called on

Tags: groovy

In Kotlin, there is the [`apply` method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html):

> ```
> inline fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T (source)
> ```
>
> Calls the specified function [block](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html#kotlin$apply(kotlin.apply.T,%20kotlin.Function1((kotlin.apply.T,%20kotlin.Unit)))/block) with `this` value as its receiver and returns `this` value.

This allows you to configure an object like the following:

```kotlin
val myObject = MyObject().apply {
  someProperty = "this value"
  myMethod()
}
```

`myObject` would be the `MyObject` after the `apply {}` call.

Groovy has the [`with` method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#with-U-groovy.lang.Closure-), which is similar:

> ```
> public static <T,U> T with(U self, 
>   @DelegatesTo(value=DelegatesTo.Target.class,target="self",strategy=1)
>   Closure<T> closure
> )
> ```
>
> Allows the closure to be called for the object reference self.
>
> ...

And an example from the doc:

```
def b = new StringBuilder().with {
  append('foo')
  append('bar')
  return it
}
assert b.toString() == 'foobar'
```

The part with the Groovy method is always having to use `return it` to return the delegate of the `with` call, which makes the code considerably more verbose.

Is there an equivalent to the Kotlin `apply` in Groovy?

Comment: I don't think there will be an equivalent, because Kotlin use *inline* to do the trick and there is no inline in Groovy .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function is called [`tap`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.5.0/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#tap-U-groovy.lang.Closure-) and is part of Groovy 2.5.  See discussions about the naming in [merge request](https://github.com/apache/groovy/pull/174).

Other than that, only `foo.with{ bar=baz; it }` can be used.  You can retrofit your own `doto`, `tap`, `apply`, ... via metaprogramming.